# How to add a specific package suffix (or packge name) to a Build Variant using gradle Android plugin

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Is it possible to set a specific package name (applicationId) to a Build Variant? (flavor + build type)

For instance, I want to add ".beta" to the package name of a variant that might be "flavor7Beta" but not the the other types of "flavor7" or other flavors of "Beta" type.

I tried

```
beta {
            ...
            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                println "variant: ${variant.name}"
                if(variant.name == "flavor7Beta") {
                    variant.applicationId = "com.domain.myapp.beta"
                }
            }
        }
```

But I got

Error:(172, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'applicationId' on com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl_Decorated@3cdafe1e.

Comment: I was using the android plugin version 0.14.2, I updated to 0.14.4 and have the same problem but using variant.applicationId and variant.applicationIdSuffix, both return that the applicationId is readonly

Comment: Also not with 1.0.0-rc1

Answer (score 1):

You should use reflection.

```
android.variantFilter { variant -> 
    def config = variant.getDefaultConfig();
    def field = config.getClass().getDeclaredField('productFlavor');
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.get(config).applicationId "com.example"
}
```

Comment: Somehow I have to specify the variant I want to change, I tried this but it doesn't work